# Symfony 3.4 Choices need array_flip

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

after update to 3.4 i must use array_flip all choice and values  - is possible to stay with classic notation - $key => $value

```
classic array = [
  1 => 'name of 1'
];
```

current symfony choices array need

```
choices array = [
       'name of 1' => 1
    ];
```

What is Best Practicle now -

```
$tags = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Keyword')->getChildren($rootKey);

'choices'=>array_flip($tags),
```

error Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!

so i need build direct query to get string or first foreach convert to string and reverse array. :)

i create static helper maybe someone need soultion.

```
   /**
     * Convert Keys to Values and Stringify new Key
     * @param $normalArray
     * @return array
     */
   public static function arrayToChoiceArray($normalArray){

       $creazyArray = [];

       foreach($normalArray as $key => $value)
           $creazyArray[(string)$value] = $key;

       return $creazyArray;

   }
```

It can be use

```
 $tags = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Keyword')->getChildren($rootKey);
```

//Now tags is [1=>Object , 2=>Object]

```
 $tags = HelperClass::arrayToChoiceArray($tags);
```

//Now tags is ['Object as string'=>$key,....] :)

Comment: what version did you update from? its been there a while

Comment: Yes, there is: don't update to 3.4. This has been around since Sf 2.8

Comment: Where i can read discussion about this ugly change ?